# getting warning mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Tags: php

I got a warning for Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array is given

```
    $item_query = "SELECT * FROM donation JOIN verification on donation.id=verification.donation_id JOIN user on user.id=donation.user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $item_query) ;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result = array(
            'email' => $r['email']
        );
        array_push($all, $result);
    }
    echo json_encode($all);
}
     else {
        echo '{"success":0}';
    }
```

Comment: Inside the fetch_assoc loop, you're reassigning the `$result` you're getting from `mysqli_query` with an array. Rename the array and it should work better. Just a case of accidentally naming two different variables with the same name.

Comment: thanks, after changing the variable name, the code is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
...
if (!empty($result)) { // check if result is empty or not..
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      // changing $result to $output to avoid confusions in using same array for printing.
      $output = array(
         'email' => $r['email']
      );
      array_push($all, $output);
    }
  }
  else {
       echo '{"success":0}';
  }
else {
  print "No results: " . $sql_query; // check whats the issue with query
}
...
```